# software to switch from AC to battery

Tags: power-management

Was just wondering if there is software or program/app that would switch the power from AC to battery on a ubuntu laptop without having to pull the power cord?  Look in google, but only found software to change power modes(high to low).  Asking if I could leave power cord attached, but run on battery if I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is suitable for people that like to let their laptop batteries discharge automatically and then recharge at a certain percentage.

## Hardware component (20 bucks)

First you need an TP-Link HS100 compatible smart plug like [this one](https://www.amazon.ca/TP-Link-Required-Anywhere-Assistant-HS105/dp/B01K1JVZOE/ref=pd_sbs_60_t_1/138-0748005-2681152?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B01K1JVZOE&pd_rd_r=c0911e01-b46e-47fb-84d2-1d6a3a798cac&pd_rd_w=V03Ee&pd_rd_wg=h3RiF&pf_rd_p=9926bb69-42b9-46e4-b788-f665992e326d&pf_rd_r=RAHJ6ASEZ9930ZHQ79HC&psc=1&refRID=RAHJ6ASEZ9930ZHQ79HC):

[image: tp-link hs-100 smart plug.png]

---

## Software component (Free)

Then you need some free Linux software like [tp-link Wi-Fi Smart Plug HS100](https://github.com/branning/hs100):

Switch plug on:

```
hs100.sh on
```

Switch plug off:

```
hs100.sh on
```

Check if plug is on or off:

```
hs100.sh check
```

Print plug system status:

```
hs100.sh status
```

[Blog about developing hs100.sh including full bash script](https://blog.georgovassilis.com/2016/05/07/controlling-the-tp-link-hs100-wi-fi-smart-plug/)

Comment: Didn't realize TP had Ubuntu software... +1

Comment: @David Technically it's Linux so works with all distro's that have a command line interface.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Good to know

Comment: Seems to be typo with plug off command.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Just a confirmation, this will work out of the box with Ubuntu plus the download, or do we need an android/ios app for setup like for chromecast.

Comment: The smart plug is a Linux computer itself. It's visible to your home WiFi network and it is easiest to use when assigned a static IP address to your router. The links above have instructions on "discovering" the IP address. The IP address can be saved to `/etc/hosts` or you can specify it each time you run the script to turn it on/off. iPhones and Android Phones are also Linux computers and they work with it too.